# Add column to csv file

Tags: bash

I have two files and I need catch the last column of a file and append to other file.

file1

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

file2

```
5 5
5 5
5 5
```

Initial proposal

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

column=$(awk '{print $(NF)}' $file1)
paste -d',' $file2 < $column
```

Expected result

file2

```
5 5 3
5 5 3
5 5 3
```

But, This script does not work yet

OBS: I do not know how many columns have in the file. I need more generic solution.

Comment: Last column has `3`s not `2`s

Comment: There are no commas in your files.  Why are you using `,` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `paste` command:

```
paste -d " " file2 <(awk '{print $NF}' file1)
5 5 3
5 5 3
5 5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To append last column of file1 to file2:

```
paste -d " " file2 <(rev file1 | cut -d " " -f 1 | rev)
```

Output:

```
5 5 3
5 5 3
5 5 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To paste the second column of file 1 to file 2:

```
   while read line; do 
       read -u 3 c1 c2 c3; 
       echo $line $c2; 
   done < file2 3< file1
```

Comment: But I do not know how many columns have in the file. I need more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl too:

```
$ paste -d ' ' file2.txt <(perl -lne 'print $1 if m/(\S+)\s*$/' file1.txt)
5 5 3
5 5 3
5 5 3
```

Or grep:

```
$ paste -d ' ' file2.txt <(grep -Eo '(\S+)\s*$' file1.txt)
5 5 3 
5 5 3
5 5 3
```